# Etherscan - Problem with smart contract verification (Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI)

Tags: remix, etherscan, contract-verification, recover

I got a smart contract created (Metamask) and deployed to Etherscan via  REMIX. On Etherscan my Metamask wallet appears as contract creator. All went fine - so far so good.

Now my problem: I try to verify my contract in Etherscan, but I can't get it work. I flattened the file, because I used library links within the code. I choosed the correct pragma solidity 0.6.6 for verification. Optimization is OFF and EVM is the correct version. All I got is:

```
Compiler Version: v0.6.6+commit.6c089d02
Optimization Enabled: False
Runs: 200

Bytecode (what we are looking for):
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{ipfs}64736f6c63430006060033

- vs what we got -

We tried looking for a match from the list of compiled contract bytecode outputs (as listed below), but was unable to find an exact match.

1) UniswapBot
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{ipfs}64736f6c63430006060033
```

I am really at the end of my ideas. I tried uncountable settings, nothing worked for me.

Any ideas? I really need to verifiy it to recover my funds on it :(

One more question comes to my mind:
Is it possible to re-deploy an already existing smart contract with HARDHAT? I got funds on my contract and I don't wann aloose them.

Thank you in advance.